# OpenLayers 4 how to detect if a polygon touches the side of another polygon

Tags: openlayers

I'm wondering if and how I would detect that a user is drawing or has drawn a polygon or other shape that overlaps.  I have attempted to use the intersectsCoordinate with no luck.  For example, the user will draw a square and then draw a circle or another square within the first square.  If the shapes drawn within that first square exceed the bounds or touch the border I need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect it by using `Map.getFeaturesAtPixel` method with `pointermove` event on Map. when you draw, the method will return any features at your mouse pointer.

```
map.on("pointermove", function(e) {
    console.log(e.pixel);
    var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(e.pixel);
    if (features && features.length >= 3) {
        // 3 => drawing cursor, line, other feature
        alert("it's on");
    }
});
```

check [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxrEzV) from OL example

Answer (score 0):

[JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/) has [good support for working with OpenLayers geometry](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/1.6.0/doc/module-org_locationtech_jts_io_OL3Parser.html) and provides a wide range of spatial predicates and operations including [`touches`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#touches(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)).